# How to monitor consumer groups in prometheus

Tags: apache-kafka, prometheus, grafana, strimzi

I'm trying to configure monitoing for apache kafka, one of my objectives is to display all active consumer groups and list their members in grafana dashboard. So far I have't found a way to do so.

Comment: You might find interesting:
https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/monitoring.html#server-metrics
https://github.com/confluentinc/jmx-monitoring-stacks/tree/7.2-post/jmxexporter-prometheus-grafana

Answer (score 2):

Since you tagged [strimzi](/questions/tagged/strimzi), that already has Kafka Exporter available, and [this blog](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/10/14/improving-prometheus-metrics/) explains that consumer group offsets are available from that